# Get length of MP3 file handle in Python

Tags: python, mp3, python-requests

I'm writing a Python program. I need something to get the (audio) length (in seconds, preferably) of an MP3 file, but the catch is that it is an open file handle (A `requests` raw request, to be exact). I could save the handle to a temporary file and read it from there, but I want to know if there is a better way. (I have to handle lots of files, and don't want to save them all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, we read a local file to get the audio duration:

```
import wave

info = wave.open('test.wav', 'r')
frames = info.getnframes()
rate = info.getframerate()

duration = frames / float(rate)
```

You can use `io.BytesIO` to get a file object from `response.content`:

```
import wave
import io
import requests


url = "http://localhost/test.wav"
r = requests.get(url)
#To get a file like object from r.content we use "io.BytesIO"
infofile = wave.open(io.BytesIO(r.content), 'r')
frames = infofile.getnframes()
rate = infofile.getframerate()

duration = frames / float(rate)
```

Comment: The BytesIO was all I actually needed (and the reason why another API which could also handle images didn't work), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "length" do you mean the audio playing time or the physical size of the file?
The length of the file is available via checking 'content-length':

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://localhost/postcard/vp1.mp3', stream=True)
>>> print r.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-length': '3119672', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'server': 'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)', 'last-modified': 'Fri, 19 Jun 2015 13:18:08 GMT', 'etag': '"2f9a38-518dec14f8cf5"', 'date': 'Sun, 22 Nov 2015 10:20:07 GMT', 'content-type': 'audio/mpeg'})
```

For the audio length, I suspect that you will have to download the file before you could ascertain its running time.

EDIT:
First install the `sox` package with apt or synaptic (sox - Sound eXchange)
Then the code is as follows:

```
import os, requests
url = "http://localhost/postcard/vp1.mp3"
pre,suff = url.rsplit('.')
r = requests.get(url)
with open('/tmp/tmp.'+suff, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024000):
        f.write(chunk)
stats=os.popen('soxi /tmp/tmp.'+suff).readlines()
for info in stats:
    print info.strip()
```

Output:

```
Input File     : '/tmp/tmp.mp3'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:02:57.08 = 7809404 samples = 13281.3 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 3.12M
Bit Rate       : 141k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
Comments       :
Title=Smoke Gets in Your Eyes
Artist=Bryan Ferry
Album=More Than This: The Best of Bryan Ferry + Roxy Music
Tracknumber=6/20
Discnumber=1
```

It's a cheat to use `soxi` but I haven't had time to install the pysox package which may to the job.
This works not only for wav files but all the audio types that `sox` understands.

Comment: I need the audio length. Also, I am willing to download the file into RAM, but I don't want to save it to the file system.

Comment: Also, some servers do not provide the Content-Length header.

Comment: Then download to /tmp (assuming that you are running Linux, if not whatever the /tmp equivalent is on your OS)